# Lag when adding records to sql lite

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, flash, air

I've made an app (Adobe Air). For the most part that app works as intended. The one issue I have is when it come to adding new records to sql lite. When adding new records (100+) the app seems to hang for 10-20 seconds while the records are added to sql lite. I know this because animations stop and no other code fires.
Once the records are added the app runs normally.

Below is the code where the issue happens.

```
    var k:Number = 0
    var arrCount:Number = cleanedArray.length
    while(k<arrCount){
        if(executeStatement("INSERT INTO wcs_tasks (taskID, stockID, rackID, pickID, countID)values('"+taskNumber+"', '"+cleanedArray[k][0]+"', '"+cleanedArray[k][1]+"', '"+cleanedArray[k][2]+"', '"+cleanedArray[k][3]+"')","0","0")[0].id == "-1"){
            k++
        }
    }
```

I did try using for() initially but that also displayed the same issue. Running any other queries once the records have been added work fine with good response times from the queries.

Below is the function that handles all the sql lite queries.

```
    function executeStatement(stmtText:String, param1:String, param2:String):Array {
if (conn.connected) {
    var arr:Array = new Array();
    stmt = new SQLStatement();
    stmt.sqlConnection = conn;

    stmt.text = stmtText;
    //stmt.parameters[0] = param1;
    //stmt.parameters[1] = param2;
    var row;
    try {
        stmt.execute();
        var result:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();

        if (result.data != null) {
            var total:int = result.data.length;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < total; i++) {
                row = result.data[i];
                arr.push( { id:row } );
            }
        } else {
            arr.push({id: -1});//no result/s
        }
    } catch (error:SQLError) {
        trace(error);
        arr.push({id: -2});//sqlite error
    }
} else {
    arr.push({id: -3});//no connection
}
return arr;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, inserting a lot of entries into a database in a loop might be slow on mobiles. There are two solutions:

1. Use an asynchronous database connection. You have a synchronous one, meaning that the app will wait until one statement is executed and then do the next one. In an asynchronous connection you just send a bunch of statements and they will be executed in the background. At some point you will get a response from the DB (result or failure). The drawback is that you need a more complex error handling on this (what do you do if you rely that the item was added to your database successfully but it wasn't. Or it was not yet added.

This goes something like that:

```
conn = new SQLConnection();
conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);

var dbFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("DBSample.db");
conn.openAsync(dbFile);
```

And then you do your statements:

```
stmt = new SQLStatement();
stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
stmt.text = stmtText;
stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, dbResult);
stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, dbError);
stmt.execute();

private function dbResult(event:SQLEvent):void
{
    var stmt:SQLStatement = event.target as SQLStatement;
    stmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, dbResult);
    stmt.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, dbError);
}

private function dbError(event:SQLEvent):void
{
    stmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, dbResult);
    stmt.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, dbError);
}
```

2. Another solution is to distribute your database job to several frames. Put your statements into an array, add an enterframe event listener and execute only a few statements from your array on each frame. Once done, remove them from your array. Continue to do so until your array is empty :)

Comment: Hi Philarmon, Thanks for taking the time to respond. I should have also pointed out that the same lag is evident in the desktop app. Looks like I will have to create some background task for this.

Comment: Using an asynchronous connection is a "backgroundy" as it may get on AIR, since this is one-threaded. You could use workers, but those are limited to desktop, afaik.